# GIMP, match images based on shared point

Tags: gimp

I am not a graphics design person and I think I may be looking for the correct language to ask the question more than anything. I have two maps that I cannot get to match up (scales are incorrect or they were scanned incorrectly.

On the maps there are common points shared by both e.g. a building or an intersection.

I would like to match them up in GIMP and export one large map. I am a GIS person, this is easy in gis but it struggles to bring the images together.

Is there a tool in GIMP that I can use to say here on this image is equal to here on this other image. If so I would greatly appreciate some help!

on the image below you can see a city hall polygon common between the two, i want to match that up with say an intersection on the other side.

[image]

Comment: Mmm... it seems a work for [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/scans/en.shtml).

Comment: Hey @Paolo, posting a link only always looks kinda spammy, even if it is legit. If you think this program/plugin/thing behind the link really is there solution, could you post it as an answer, including an explanation of what it does and why you think it's the tool for the job? Thanks.

Comment: @PieBie this question is broad and is difficult give a punctual answer. My hint was intended to invite dave* to do something by itself (there is no trace of efforts in this question). Hugin is very versatile in order to compose tiles of a bigger image and rearrange the perspective, and in this context could be useful.

Comment: In that case you should flag the question as too broad and comment explaining why you flagged it.

Comment: Hi dave, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

Take the new map to the separate layer over the old map in the background layer and set the top layer to the "Difference" mode. Then using the GIMP transformation tools you can perfectly match the maps.
Actually you may try not only the "Difference" mode, but others, too, depending on the details that you match, but the "Difference" is perfect exactly for your case if the colors of the maps are similar (ideally if they are same).